# variance of k element average of sequence

Tags: probability, statistics

I want to know how to theoretically find the variance of a sequence obtained by taking k element averages of another known sequence.

Lets say Sequence S1 has some N elements that are say uniformly distributed(for simplicity) between -1.0 and 1.0. Assuming N to be very large, the mean of the sequence will be 0(approximately) and variance will be $\frac{2^2}{12}$.

S1 -> ${a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,.......,a_N}$

A new sequence S2 is formed by taking k element average of sequence S1.

S2 -> ${b_1,b_2,b_3,....,b_{N-k}}$
where $b_i = \frac{a_i + a_{i+1} + a_{i+2} + .... + a_{i+k}}{k}$

Intuitively I can say that the mean of S2 will also be 0(approximately). But what about the variance of S2. I remember there is some formula/method in probability and statistics that directly gives the mean and variance of the new sequence(S2) given the mean and variance of S1. But I don't remember it.

Comment: The individual variances are $1/3$, the variance of the sum of $k$ (**independent**) elements is $k/3$, so the variance of the average is $(1/k^2)(k/3)$, that is, $1/(3k)$.

Comment: @André Nicolas: Thanks. I think your answer makes sense since I expect the variance to decrease as k keeps increasing.

Comment: The solution by Ross Millikan is good, but there is a typo at the end. Note that if $X$ is a random variable, and $c$ is a constant, then the variance of $cX$ is $c^2$ times the variance of $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add terms, the means and variances add.  Since the mean of each element is $0$, the mean of a sum is also $0$.  As you say, the variance of each element is $\frac {2^2}{12}=\frac 13$  The variance of the sum of $k$ terms is then $\frac k3$, so the variance of the average of $k$ terms is $\frac 1{3k}$.

Comment: There is a typo at the end, the variance is $\frac{1}{3k}$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think we need to clarify a little terminology. Assuming OP is concerning about the sample mean of the sequence:

$$ \bar{A}_N = \frac {1} {N} \sum_{i=1}^N A_i $$

Then as what OP said, the theoretical mean of this estimator is equal to the true population mean (i.e. it is an unbiased estimator).

$$ E[\bar{A}_N] = E[A_1]$$

When OP mentioned

> the mean of sequence will be $0$ (approximately)

it seems that OP is stating the sample mean of the sequence will converge to the theoretical mean in probability / a.s. as $N \to \infty$, by LLN

$$\bar{A}_N \stackrel {p} {\to} E[A_1]$$

From all the answers/comments, I think we just stick to the first statement, and thus the expectation is exact for every $N$, not only approximately. Please correct me if I misinterpret your question intention.

Now begins. This question reminds me of a $MA(k)$ model, and we are dealing with the sample mean
$$ \bar{B} = \frac {1} {N} \sum_{i=1}^N B_i $$
and
$$ B_i = \frac {1} {k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} A_{i+j}, i = 1, 2, \ldots, N - k + 1$$
As a $MA(k)$ model, those $B_i$ which within $k$-lags are correlated, so the variance of this sample mean $\bar{B}_N$ differs from the first example $\bar{A}_N$. Assuming $N > 2(k-1)$, then by simple counting,

$$ \bar{B} = \frac {1} {kN} \left[\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} iA_i + \sum_{i=k}^{N-k+1} kA_i + \sum_{i=N-k+2}^{N} (N-i+1)A_i\right]$$

As a result

$$ \begin{align} 
Var[\bar{B}] & = \frac {Var[A_1]} {k^2N^2}  \left[\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}i^2
+ (N-2k+2)k^2 + \sum_{i=N-k+2}^{N} (N-i+1)^2\right] \\
& = \frac {Var[A_1]} {k^2N^2}\left[k^2N - 2(k-1)k^2 + \frac {(k-1)k(2k-1)} {6} \times 2 \right] \\
& = \frac {Var[A_1]} {kN^2}\left[kN - 2(k-1)k + \frac {(k-1)(2k-1)} {3}\right] \\
& = \frac {Var[A_1]} {kN^2}\left[kN + \frac {(k-1)(2k-1) - 6(k-1)k} {3} \right] \\
& = \frac {Var[A_1]} {N} \left[1 - \frac{(k-1)(4k+1)} {3kN}\right]
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for taking time and explaining the math. Though it is much involved and has lesser intuition I will use this for further analysis in case the problem needs to be analyzed deeper. The answer provided by @André Nicolas was sufficient for my current use case where I just wanted to know if increase in k causes the variance to decrease and how much I should increase k to achieve a variance below some limit.

Comment: edit: For my level of math this analysis looks involved(did not mean to be critical)

Comment: just want to emphasize that like a MA model, the terms $B_i$ here are not mutually independent. (and their correlation weaken when the lag between terms increase) So when you are calculating the variance, theoretically you should not omit the covariance term.

Comment: what do you mean by "their correlation weaken when the lag between terms increase"? I understand that there is a k element lag between $A_i$ and $B_i$ but $B_i$ and $B_{i+1}$ are sequential for any value of k(assuming N>k) right? Or by lag do you mean something else.

Comment: I mean the correlation of $B_1, B_2$ will be greater than $B_1, B_3$, and etc.

Comment: Ok. I agree. Just another doubt. Will your model and variance converge to @Andre Nicolas answer for the ideal case(statistical mean and theoretical mean and variance of A being same).

Comment: From your description, you are interested in the sample mean of those $B_i$, where each $B_i$ is a sample mean of i.i.d. $A_j$. So as you see from my answer, the first order is still $ \frac {Var[A_1]} {N}$. The answer is pretty much agree asymptotically, I just provide the actual correct variance by including the covariance term which cannot be ignored theoretically, and at least when the sample size is not big.